# SQL: Count number of distinct records based on attribute value in an xml

Tags: mysql, count, xml

Say I have following xml

```
<Operations>
  <Info Id="2265" cId="2" aId="5" />
  <Info Id="2266" cId="2" aId="5" />
  <Info Id="2266" cId="2" aId="6" />
  <Info Id="2267" cId="2" aId="5" />
  <Info Id="2267" cId="2" aId="6" />
</Operations>
```

Without inserting the values into table by allocating extra space I want to count the number of nodes with distinct value on attributes `cId` and `aId`.

Currently I am doing it by inserting the same into table, but the data is very large and is taking a lot of temp space during execution.

Is there any way?

Expected output for above would be `3`

Comment: Load the data into a table, then do a simple SQL SELECT with COUNT and GROUP BY.

Comment: Can't load into a table, space concerns

Comment: "Space concerns"??  Is it gigabytes?

Comment: 300MBish kind, loading into temp table would just clutter my RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Don't force it into RAM; let it use disk as needed.  Do you have it in a table?  Or only in XML?

There is probably a single `LOAD DATA` statement to convert that from XML to a table defined thus:

```
CREATE TABLE Operations (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cid TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    aid TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The table will probably be smaller than your 300MB.  Let it spill to disk if it needs to.  (You have very little control anyway.)  How big can the ids be?  I picked the smallest datatype, but that assumes the numbers are between 0 and 255.  Pick a larger datatype if needed.

Then do

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cid, aid)
     FROM Operations;
```

That seems to be "number of nodes with distinct value on attributes cId and aId", but it looks like the answer will be 2, namely [2,5] and [2,6].  If `Info_id` is relevant to the counting, please explain how.  (That may necessitate including it in the `LOAD DATA`.

If you are exporting data from a spreadsheet,...  Well, I see XML as an awful way to do it.  Using a CSV file is easier and faster as an RDBMS-friendly format.  After that, 3 SQL statements achieve the goal:  CREATE TABLE, LOAD DATA, SELECT.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking at OpenXML doc, is there any way to read using openxml and count on demand

Comment: Sorry, I don't know OpenXML.  And my dislike for XML will probably keep me from ever learning it.